# Чем можно заменить LruCache?

Tags: android

Использую в своем приложении для кэширования картинок LruCache по [примеру из документации](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). Мое приложение может работать начиная с версии Android 1.6, поэтому для LruCache приходится подключать support library. Можно ли чем-то заменить LruCache, чтобы убрать библиотеку? Позволит уменьшить размер APK.

Comment: [offtop]

1.6? Вы серьёзно? Сейчас уже устройства с 2.2 составляют менее 2 процентов от общего числа устройств, а 1.5-1.6 и вовсе в [статистику][1] не вошли. Не уверен даже, будет ли вообще работать Google Play на таком устройстве, не говоря уже о установке требуемых многими приложениями Google Play Services/Framework.

[/offtop]

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform

Comment: А по сабжу — вот вам [исходники][1] `LruCache`. Если заглянете во внутренности, то увидите, что никаких сложностей в портировании этого нет, да и в реализации с нуля тоже, на самом деле.

  [1]: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/util/LruCache.java

Comment: Кстати говоря, прогон тем же ProGuard'ом с включённой опцией `shrinking` даст вам тот же эффект в плане уменьшения размера итогового apk — удалит все неиспользуемые классы из `support library`, оставив лишь используемые, то бишь `LruCache`.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, это то что нужно.

Comment: Более сильное сокращение размера даст разделение на две версии приложения - одно для старых двайсов, другое для новых. Мои наблюдения показывают, что много места забирают картинки и прочие ресурсы. На андоиде 1.6 с экраном 320х240 картинки для xdpi не нужны.